# Сделать симметричным блочный контент, расположенный внутри div'a в несколько строк

Tags: html, css, width, центрирование

нужно ещё учитывать, что не всегда в строке будут 4 товара(!)

Вообще, согласен на любые меры симметричности: размера родителя относительно детей, width детей для заполнения родителя или центрирование детей по родителю.

Если у вас есть идеи по любому из вышеизложенных сценариев, то буду благодарным их выслушать.

[image: шаблон]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов много, вот некоторые:

```css
div[class^="e"] {
  position: relative;
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div[class^="e"]>div {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}

.e1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.e1>div {
  margin: 10px;
}

.e2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.e2>div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 10px;
}

.e3 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.e3>div {
  width: 18%!important;
  margin: 1%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="e1">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="e2">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="e3">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```